# call function within a custom widget that is a callback

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to call the function SetLoginButtonLabel in widget Login from inside the function SetLoginInfo -- SetLoginInfo is a call back from the widget LogInDB.  When I try to call it just using this.SetLoginButtonLabel I get error SetLoginButtonLabel is undefined.  I'm also trying hitch as shown below, but thats not working either.  There are several different functions I'd like to call from SetLoginInfo -- How could I use hitch or some other method to make this work?

Thanks

---Widget Login

```
...
postCreate: function() {
 var SetLab = lang.hitch(this, "SetLoginButtonLabel");

}

Login: function() //call the database
{

LoginDB.Login("http://xxx/John Smith", this.SetLoginINfo)
},


SetLoginInfo: function(LoginData) //call back from LoginDB
{
//I've tried:
this.SetLogingButtonLabel("status"); //get an undefined error

//and 
SetLab("Logout");//this just seems to get lost

},

SetLoginButtonLabel: function(status)
{
//
}

.......
```

---Widget LoginDB

```
define(['dojo/store/Memory', 'dojo/_base/xhr', "dojo/data/ObjectStore", 'dojo/_base/json'],
//functions to get data and fill data stores
function (Memory, xhr, ObjectStore) {
    var TicketStore;
    return {
        //login
        Login: function (url, callback) {
            xhr.get({//send data
                url: url,
                handleAs: "json",
                load: function (result) {
                    var LoginData = result;
                    callback(LoginData);

                },
                error: function (err) { }

            });
        }



    }

});
```

Comment: I've also tried calling the DB widget like this:
 LoginDB.Login(s, lang.hitch(this.SetTOC));

still get undefined error

Comment: rather it is this:
 LoginDB.Login(s, lang.hitch(this, SetTOC));

Comment: This does work:
LoginDB.Login(s, this.SetLoginInfo, lang.hitch(this, this.SetLoginButtonLabel));
however I want to call a bunch of functions from setLoginIfo

Comment: SetTOC in the above comments should be SetLoginInfo (I changed the function name on my post

Answer (score 0):

this made it work:

```
LoginDB.Login(s, lang.hitch(this, this.SetLoginInfo));
```

All of my calls within SetLoginInfo I put a this on the front:

```
this.SetLoginButtonLabel("Logged In");
```